Procrastination of cases requiring concentration
Greetings to all respected forum participants!
Throughout many years, starting from school, I've noticed that compared to my peers, colleagues, classmates, etc., I often ended up being the least productive. I could spend a lot of time and effort on a task (especially creative ones - simple calculation or rewriting tasks were easy and quick, where I didn't need to concentrate heavily), which others completed faster and more easily. Meanwhile, my peers would manage to do something else in their free time or simply feel less exhausted, whereas I would spend extensive time and energy.
Recently, I've realized that I'm a perfectionist. I spend a lot of time and effort to prepare and present a perfect result that I will achieve on the first try.
Moreover, I have a deep-rooted fear of failure that originated in childhood. So if I need to do something responsible and present it to others, I'll spend a lot of time alone to be 100% confident in my abilities.
From all of this stems my primary problem, which people have pointed out since childhood - distraction.
For three months, I've tried to incorporate meditation into my daily life as a habit. I managed to create daily training routines at work and home when they're tied to a schedule, time, or place, but meditation is consistently avoided by me. I even set myself a limit of 5 minutes of meditation.
Even the prospect of 5 minutes of meditation often feels like torture, especially after a hard workday. So with mild fatigue, I always found excuses for why I shouldn't meditate today.
Procrastinating meditation is just the tip of the iceberg. Unfortunately, because of this, I'm low-productivity at work, do little in my hobby and personal development, and very often try to avoid concentration.
At the same time, I don't have a strong phone addiction. I don't watch TikTok for hours, can sit at home in silence for hours and calmly read a book. But the moment I want to read a book, I'll postpone it because I'll be afraid to concentrate and spend time reading just one book.
Friends, have any of you encountered this? What solutions do you see from a Buddhist perspective?

I think it's best not to set a time limit or goal. The only time is right now; it's the only time anything can ever happen. If you stay in the immediate present with what's happening here, then you're not really creating the mental framework to be worried about "how long is this gonna take, or what if I'm missing out on something else that's happening." What if the most important thing is this.
Ajahn Brahm recommends silent, present moment awareness throughout the day as preparation for sitting meditation. That way, you're almost doing sitting meditation already, and it's not much of a transition. Plus, mindfulness in all postures is standard Buddhist practice. Walking meditation is standard practice. There's no chance for fidgeting when you're walking.
The classic antidote the Buddha taught for the five hindrances hindrance of restlessness and anxiety, is stillness, which can happen by keeping your attention on one thing and ignoring everything else; that's how samatha meditation is usually done. That, and letting go; although consciously letting go of something means now you're paying attention to that, instead of the meditation object, which means your attention is moving back and forth, and that's not stillness/concentration.
But Ajahn Brahm, and most teachers, also recommend not forcing things. Forcing your mind makes it resist and rebel. He says if your mind isn't cooperating with the practice then just let it go, to do whatever it wants, and you'll be surprised how cooperative and quiet it becomes. I've actually found it works, almost immediately. It's like as soon as you give it that freedom it suddenly loses interest in whatever it thought it wanted to do.

I often ended up being the least productive. I could spend a lot of time and effort on a task
There's a (modern, non-Buddhist) educational theory that it's better to praise children for "how much effort" they put into a task, rather than "how well they do".
Children who are praised for "doing well" will be discouraged when they have a more difficult task (which they can't do so well) -- whereas a child who is praised for "effort" will try ...
Recently, I've realized that I'm a perfectionist.
Perhaps that's not bad. Even some mundane tasks -- like driving (a car bicycle in traffic) -- ought to be near-perfect, isn't that so?
Morality might be a matter of selecting the right activity -- some are more or less beneficial to perfect.
According to modern psychology and probably Buddhism too, to be engaging or absorbing an activity must be not too difficult and not too easy.
I find "watching television" is both too difficult and too easy now, though I used to watch it as a child -- "too easy" because it requires almost nothing from me, "too hard" because I cannot affect it (except to switch it off).
Another classic advice is, to reflect on what you do, see which activities are regrettable i.e. which ones cause "remorse", and stop doing (don't repeat) those -- i.e. learn to prefer activities which you don't regret.

Starting by building a strong foundation.
Dana; generosity, giving, relinquishing (ie ordained Sangha, homeless, relatives, workers, friends, family). (see here on a quote from Ajahn Lee)
Sila; 5 or 8 precepts, morality, good actions by the 3 doors of body speech and mind.

""Five blessings, householders, accrue to the righteous person through
his practice of virtue: great increase of wealth through his
diligence; a favorable reputation; a confident deportment, without
timidity, in every society, be it that of nobles, brahmans,
householders, or ascetics; a serene death; and, at the breaking up of
the body after death, rebirth in a happy state, in a heavenly world."
(reference)

Bhavana; cultivation of wholesome mental qualities and contemplation inline with Dhamma. (such as the six recollections)
Saddha; Faith in the Lord Buddha. A willingness to follow the teaching and medicine prescribed by that Great Doctor. Putting down all doubts and really following the instructions given so suffering may be healed. (Mahanama Sutta)
Viriya; the energy to do the work, not too high, not too low, in the middle, being even such that it is good for striving.
Sati; mindfulness, presence of mind, clarity of mind, first foundation of mindfulness, clear awareness.
Samadhi; cultivation of meditation based on Right View (that inevitably leads to seeing clearly into the three characteristics of existence; annica, dukkha & annata)
Punnya; wisdom, the accumulation, development and perfection of True insight, understanding and wisdom.
If you look here at Ajahn Lee's Craft of the heart, you will get a good understandings of the basics of practice.
So the idea in the practice is to build up samadhi or bhavana based on Sila.
One needs a strong foundation. This ability to build up mental cultivation or absorbtion is like developing our persistence, staying power, gumption, ability to stick with, to sustain effort and energy, to overcome obstacles, to really do the work.
Then this ability sustain efforts in our spiritual practice and will start to help us in other aspects of life.
Luang Por Thate says once we have samadhi, we can use that power however we like as long as we don't hurt ourselves or others.
Goals are fine. Goals are useful. Goals can be used to realise Nibbana. Just see if our goals are serving our high ideals and inner good, and see how we are relating to them, if we are living up to them.
We each have different qualities. So for some, mindfulness will be more difficult then others. When there is mindfulness, then the practice will flow more naturally, as one can keep one's mind on the chosen task.
Bhavana is a good place to start, if mindfulness is weak, as it leads to samadhi.
AN 6:38, Copyright Wisdom Pub, Bhikkhu Bodhi (here for study purposes only)

Then a certain brahmin approached the Blessed One and exchanged
greetings with him. When they had exchanged greetings and cordial
talk, he sat down to one side and said to the Blessed One:
“Master Gotama, I hold such a thesis and view as this: ‘There is no
self-initiative; there is no initiative taken by others.’”
“Brahmin, I have never seen or heard of anyone holding such a thesis
and view as this. For how can one who comes on his own and returns on
his own say: ‘There is no self-initiative; there is no initiative
taken by others’?
(1) “What do you think, brahmin? Does the element of instigation
exist?”
“Yes, sir.”
“When the element of instigation exists, are beings seen to instigate
activity?”
“Yes, sir.”
“When beings are seen to instigate activity because the element of
instigation exists, this is the self-initiative of beings; this is the
initiative taken by others.
... “When beings are seen to persist in activity because the element of
persistence exists, this is the self-initiative of beings; this is the
initiative taken by others.
... “When beings are seen to exert themselves in activity because the
element of exertion exists, this is the self-initiative of beings;
this is the initiative taken by others.
... “When beings are seen to be possessed of strength because the element
of strength exists, this is the self-initiative of beings; this is the
initiative taken by others.
... “When beings are seen to continue [in an action] because the element
of continuation exists, this is the self-initiative of beings; this is
the initiative taken by others.
... “When beings are seen to act with force because the element of force
exists, this is the self-initiative of beings; this is the initiative
taken by others.

This is a good example of the factors required for us to do anything. It sounds like these factors would help one become clear on how to apply oneself. Of course, the factors of practice are also important for one who is living as a Buddhist.

Thank you for your reply! Could you give me more specific recommendations that could help me in my situation? I'm familiar with the concepts you're talking about, but I don't know where to start or how to apply them to my situation.

@Egor, ok did full re-write. There is a sutta that talks about the factors of persistence I will try to find.

+1 for the need to work on a solid foundation. There is no shortcuts. I amended certain wordings, hope it didn't deviate from any meanings.

@Desmon ... great. I can't see my own mistakes often so anumodana. Yes very important to have the strong foundation. It is something that can not be overstepped by anyone!

The Buddha taught (in SN 51.13) to have love/enthusiasm (chanda) for what you do is the basis for concentration & success in that endeavour.

In addition to what DhammaDhatu says, it says thought is the cause of chanda:

“Thought is the source of desire.”
“Chando kho, devānaminda, vitakkanidāno vitakkasamudayo vitakkajātiko
vitakkapabhavo; vitakke sati chando hoti; vitakke asati chando na
hotī”ti.

Perhaps a better definition of chanda in this context is given by Ajahn Sucitto:

Desire as an eagerness to offer, to commit, to apply oneself to
meditation, is called chanda.

Of vitarka with regards to happiness it is said:

And when, following after happiness, I have perceived that bad
qualities were diminished and good qualities developed, then such
happiness was to be followed. Now of such happiness as is accompanied
by pre-occupation and travail of mind, and of such as is not so
accompanied, the latter is the more excellent.

More descriptions of vitakka

Pranayama (lowering breathing frequency) improves concentration. But technical practices either don't work or bring adverse results when practiced without:

Merit accumulation (dana)
Moral discipline (śīla)
Mental training (bhāvanā)

What to do - shortened answer

Practice pranayama regularly.
Dana - make donations (even small is OK) every month. Your best bet is Dalai Lama or his foundation.
Sila - don't eat meat or drink/smoke on days when you practice pranayama. If you can become full-time vegetarian - even better!
Bhavana - read Buddhist texts or meditate on 4 immeasurables, preferably 2x the time spent on pranayama. You can start with Illuminating the path to Enlightenment


Pranayma
Choose maximum interval length that you are comfortable with for at least 10 minutes.
For beginners: inhale/hold/exhale in 1:1:1 proportion, e. g. 10 sec / 10 sec / 10 sec.
Advanced: inhale/hold/exhale in 1:2:2 proportion, e. g. 10 sec / 20 sec / 20 sec
As you progress, go for longer and longer intervals. If you can breathe once every 1 minute, you will have some concentration. If you can breathe once every 2 minutes, you will have good concentration.

Dana
There are 3 types of charity: material, emotional and wisdom-sharing.

Material: donating money or material things to those in need or spiritual practitioners. Many non-profit organizations waste money, and world is full of pseudo-gurus, so check very thoroughly where your money is going.
Emotional: listening to people who suffer, which results in emotional relief. Hard to go wrong with this one.
Sharing wisdom: once you thoroughly tested and memorized some spiritual teaching yourself, you can share it. This is very dangerous, since spreading wrong view is considered more harmful than killing in Buddhism. So don't do it at first.


Sila
Memorize Buddhist 10 commandments for laypeople by rote, and start integrating them into your daily life. To clarify typical confusion - not eating meat/fish is a part of the 1st commandment (to abstain from killing).
The 10 precepts are to abstain from:
killing, stealing, adultery, use of intoxicants
lying, slandering and speech that causes discord, empty talk
greed, anger/hatred, wrong view (ignorance)

Bhavana

Teach yourself too look at all things from the perspective of karmic causes/consequences in accordance with Buddha's teachings.
Gain understanding of why attaining liberation (Nirvana) is the ultimate goal, what are the steps to reach it (8-fold Noble path, 8 limbs of Yoga, 6 paramitas).
Develop a desire to reach the ultimate goal.



What are the "10 commandments for laypeople"? Did you mean "eight"? In Theravada there are 5 or 8 precepts for laypeople -- the 10th is to avoid taking money and is more for novice monks and nuns. And maybe there are Eight Mahayana Precepts which are about the same.

@ChrisW, I meant these 10:
Abstaining from killing, stealing, adultery, using intoxicants, lying, slandering, empty talk, greed, anger, wrong view (ignorance)
I should've mentioned that in the answer, because different schools group precepts differently. For example, nurturing compassion and generosity prevents anger/hatred/killing and greed/stealing, and you get 8 precepts instead of 10.
